# SSRS: #ERROR when trying to populate field

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

I think the reason behind my error has to do with multiple rows in my dataset, but I'm not 100% sure. Here is the report structure:
[image]

As you can see, the email address is grouped only under the ServiceShop, but when I preview it, I get the dreaded #Error.

[image]

My thinking is that it has something to do with the multiple rows, as seen here in the query results:

[image]

Is this in fact the problem? If so, is there a way for me to get the one email address to populate my textbox? Because more of my query isn't visible, let me clarify that I can't simply put a DISTINCT in there to reduce the rows; the multiple rows are necessary on the basis of each row having payment data that is aggregated in the report.

Comment: The "dreaded #error" usually shows more detail about what the problem is in the output pane of Visual Studio.

Comment: try using `=FIRST(Fields!email_address.Value)` This will use the first value found in the current scope, which in your case should be the ServiceShop group

Comment: Great idea Alan, but it didn't seem to like that, still have the error.

Comment: Dale, the only output issue I can see is this: `[rsAggregateOfInvalidExpressionDataType] The Value expression for the textrun 'email_address.Paragraphs[0].TextRuns[0]' uses an aggregate function with an expression that returned a data type not valid for the aggregate function.`